# Profit Brought forward

Tags: stocks, investing, stock-analysis, accounting

While reading the annual report, of a company in which i'm interested, i stumbled upon the notion of Profit Brought forward in the proposed of appropriation section of the report.

It goes like this :

The Board of Directors propose that profit be appropriated as follows:
Brought forward: 33,432,333
Profit for the year: 43,841,555
Total: 77,273,888

I couldn't find an explanation on google.